# Finding an extra letter in two rows

Tags: python

**My exercise text:**

"There are 2 strings **s** and **t**, both in lowercase letters. String **t** is obtained by mixing letters of string **s** and adding 1 letter to a random position. You need to find the added letter."

***Input format*:**
The input is strings **s** and **t**, separated by a line break. Line lengths do not exceed 1000 characters. Lines are never empty.

***Output format*:**
Print the extra letter.

**Example:**

***input:***

abcd

abcde

***output:***

e

This is my code but it works not completely. For example, for inputs ***fff*** and ***fffd*** program works and print ***d***. But for inputs ***go*** and ***ogg*** program doesn't work.

Please, help me to find out how to complete my code. I think maybe I should sort rows before comparing them, but I don't know how to do  it correctly.

```
s = str(input())
list_s = list(s)
t = str(input())
list_t = list(t)
res_1 = [x for x in list_s + list_t if x not in list_s or x not in list_t]
res = ' '.join(list(map(str, res_1)))
print(res)
```

Comment: @KellyBundy it is not what i am telling to do, it is my exercise text.

Comment: Your approach would be good if the added letter did not occur in the original string at some point. Then, you would always find the correct string. However, if there are 5 `e` in one string and 6 `e` in the other, you would have to find this difference. Therefore, looping over all letters to see whether they are in the original string won't work. Try using the `.remove()` method of lists to remove all letters of the original string from the new one. This method only ever removes one instance. That should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
s = str(input())
t = str(input())

for character in s:
    t = t.replace(character, '', 1)

print(t)
```

Comment: Thanks, its perfect

Answer (score 0):

This solution takes advantage of the fact that Counters will count characters in strings automatically, and that you can subtract one from the other to get the remaining character.

```
from collections import Counter

s = Counter(str(input('Enter string s:')))
t = Counter(str(input('Enter string t:')))

print((t-s).most_common()[0][0])
```

Comment: Could also do `print(*(t-s))`.

Comment: And you'll likely get a "Wrong answer" judgement because you print something other than what's specified.

Comment: Thanks! its new functions for me